# How to open a file the same name as defined in the String?

Tags: java, android, string, listview, onclicklistener

I'm creating a lyric app and I need some help in coding the next processes I need.
I created a ListView and added some Strings on it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String titles[] = new String [] {"Amazing Grace", "How Great Thou Art", 
"King of All Kings", "What A Beautiful Name"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.titlelist);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> 
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,titles);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
}
```

Now the next step is to create an OnItemClickListener and let's say
if "Amazing Grace" was selected from the list, 
it will look for a file the same name as it is defined in the String.
For example : "Amazing Grace.xml" //even with the space included

so the logic will be like : open filelocation/"title that was selected".xml

I can't use "case" since I will be creating lots of song titles and add more as I update the app.
Thanks for reading, I'd really appreciate any help with this ;)

Comment: google: java string concatenation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To open file:

```
int selected = 0; // set selected to index of what is selected
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), //folder location where you store the files
titles[selected]+".xml"); //in case of xml files. If other types, you'll need to add case for diff types
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent fileOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
fileOpenintent .setDataAndType(path, "application/xml"); //for xml MIME types are text/xml and application/xml
try {
    startActivity(fileOpenintent);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

}
```

Your biggest issue as you explained it was how to handle multiple file names. That's this part of code: `titles[selected]+".xml"`

Comment: I forgot to use a webview. the 1) int pos = parent.getPositionForView(view) // assigned in the onclick and 2)webView1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + titles[pos]+".xml"); will do the trick. Credits to your idea with  titles[selected]+".xml". Thanks Man!

Answer (score 0):

You should map Your lyrics, so when You click on item with `pos = 5` You will know what item's ps correlates with what file(or xml).

Here is the sample how to map ids with filenames:

```
HashMap<String,Strin> lyricsMap = new HashMap<>();
lyricsMap(0, R.raw.song_lyric0);
lyricsMap(1, R.raw.song_lyric1);
lyricsMap(2, R.raw.song_lyric2);
lyricsMap(3, R.raw.song_lyric3);
lyricsMap(4, R.raw.song_lyric4);
lyricsMap(5, R.raw.song_lyric5);
lyricsMap(6, R.raw.song_lyric6);
//..
```

Here is the sample how to use OnItemClickListener:

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
        int rawResId = lyricsMap.get(pos);

        //here comes the method for returning lyrics for file by it's resource id

        //...
    }
};
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
```

P.S I assume You are not working on database items, otherwise You should use `id` instead of `pos` value.

Comment: Let's say the lyric titles I put in each position is not sorted alphabetically, Position 0 = "Be Like You"  Position 1 = "Zealous Fighter" Position 2 = "Amazing Grace"   ..If I use a command that sorts this titles out, will they change their positions or still retain them? Coz I need to know if this method works even if I just add more song titles on the list without sorting alphabetically the whole thing again and again manually